# Different Wallpaper if two monitors are attached

Tags: macos, display, multiple-monitors, applescript, desktop-customization

I am working on my MacBook Pro. In the office I have 1 27" Monitor attached to it, at home I tend to work without an second monitor. For that setup I want to change the wallpaper if no 2nd monitor is attached.

Is there a app that helps me do that? Can I do this with applescript without manual activating that script?

Comment: I have googled a bit and if i would build a cocoa app for that i would have to use applicationDidChangeScreenParameters. But i am not as good as i need to be in cocoa development for that.

Hopefully someone already wrote an app for that :)

Comment: Sadly I haven't found anything that fittet my neads. I have written a little Cococa App that does exactly what I needed. Hopefully I will be able to add some final finishing touches and release it as open source.

Comment: See:
http://superuser.com/questions/170545/how-can-i-run-a-script-whenever-i-plug-in-an-external-monitor

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to take a look at [Hyperspaces](https://hyperspacesapp.com). Although this is for Multiple SPaces, I don’t remember if it will let you specify a different wallpaper per-screen and this might not be what you’re looking for.

Comment: That's not what I need. What I needed was a little app that could detect what monitor setup I am currently use (2 Monitor Setup at Work, 1 Monitor in the subway, 2 different Monitor Setup at home) and sets the Dock and the Wallpaper accordingly.

Hopefully I will release my little cocoa app soon.