# How can I run a script whenever I plug in an external monitor?

Tags: macos, applescript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reset Mac OS X Windows Position after de-attaching external monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/331/reset-mac-os-x-windows-position-after-de-attaching-external-monitor)

I use my laptop at work, where I have a second monitor, and at home, where I don't.  When I plug in the external display, I'd like the Mac to automatically run a shell script or AppleScript that will reposition a bunch of windows to their "standard" external-monitor locations.  Is there any Apple Event or similar thing that can launch my scripts when I plug in a monitor?  Alternatively, are there any utilities that specifically do this?  I looked at Breeze, but it saves window state on an app-by-app basis, and doesn't detect monitors being plugged or unplugged.

Comment: Duplicate of [Reset Mac OS X Windows Position after de-attaching external monitor](http://superuser.com/questions/331/reset-mac-os-x-windows-position-after-de-attaching-external-monitor)?

Comment: Weird... I did ask the same question, but got a much better answer. All the answers to that thread were of the "Here's something you can manually run" variety, not the nicely-automated Marco Polo.  Please do merge the answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a piece of software called MarcoPolo that lets you execute various actions (including scripts) when the physical state of a box changes (you can switch on stuff like external power, external monitor, ambient light, time of day, attached drives, visible wifi networks, ip address, etc)

Comment: See http://www.controlplaneapp.com/ which is currently maintained.

Comment: Yup, I had forgotten that this answer was here.  I've moved to control plane a while ago.  It works really well.